# Microsoft Report Builder convert decimal to HH:MM

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have a report which currently shows Time used in decimal format 0:24 as one example.  I want to convert this to HH:MM so 0:24 should be 14:40.

To achieve this I have written the following expression

`=Floor(Fields!Time_Used.Value) & CInt(Fields!Time_Used.Value - Floor(Fields!Time_Used.Value) * 60)`

In addition I have tried a more simplistic approach

```
=Fields!Time_Used.Value * 60
```

Neither option works and the field returns #Error is my logic or math wrong here?

Comment: Can you explain, how do you  0:24 to 14:40?Wha format is 0:24 in?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the time is in decimal hours then I think you are saying that `0.24` (not `0:24`) means 14.4 minutes not (14:40 which sounds like 14H and 40 mins). If this is the case then you simply need to multiple by 60 to get the number of minutes.

Below is the output from a quick report. The left column shows the tables from my table (e.g. 0.24, 0.75, 15.75 etc).

The second column is simply the first column * 60 to give the number of minutes.

The final column shows this duration as a "time". To do this I used DATEADD() and added the number of seconds (1st column * 3600) to todays date, then formatted the column to show just the time part.

Here's the expression for the 2nd column

```
=Fields!decHours.Value*60
```

Here's the expression for the 3rd column

```
=DATEADD(DateInterval.Second, Fields!decHours.Value * 3600, today())
```

Here's the format code used in the 3rd column

```
HH:mm:ss
```

Here's the final output..

[image]

So your original example of 0.24 is 14.4 minutes which is 14 minutes and 24 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I ended up querying this with my manager as I couldn't get past the fact the field was reporting on a data type of time which was in HH:MM format.  However, I had been asked to convert this to HH:MM, I didn't originally question this as I assumed the person making the request knew something I didn't.  I eventually queried their interpretation of the reported data and realised they had made an error and needed the field converted to decimal.  I have now achieved this by adding a calculated field with the following expression.

```
=Hour(Fields!Time_Used.Value) + Minute(Fields!Time_Used.Value) / 60
```

This achieved the desired result and fixed my issue.  Thanks to all for taking the time to respond.